# Remove Duplicates in an array in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

My array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [month] => November [Average Purchase Price] => 2.52 [Total Purchase Gallons] => 84000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [month] => October [Average Purchase Price] => 2.615 [Total Purchase Gallons] => 63000 ) 
[2] => Array ( [month] => November [Average Customer Price] => 2.79 [Total Customer Gallons] => 25000 ) 
[3] => Array ( [month] => October [Average Customer Price] => 2.9050000000000002 [Total Customer Gallons] => 5500 ) )
```

I want to be able to echo out the [month] and not have it duplicated, but still associate the other values to the correct month.  To get to this point I have done an array_merge to put them together like you see them.

Separately they look like this:

#1

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [month] => November [Average Purchase Price] => 2.52 [Total Purchase Gallons] => 84000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [month] => October [Average Purchase Price] => 2.615 [Total Purchase Gallons] => 63000 ) )
```

#2

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [month] => November [Average Customer Price] => 2.79 [Total Customer Gallons] => 25000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [month] => October [Average Customer Price] => 2.9050000000000002 [Total Customer Gallons] => 5500 ) )
```

I have tried array_unique and that does not work.  I am using a foreach statement to echo out the values.

Thank you!

The SQL Queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT month, AVG(price) AS 'Average Purchase Price', SUM(gallons) as 'Total Purchase Gallons' from purchase_contracts
group BY month";
$purch = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($purch))
{ 
    $purch_items[] = $rows;
}


$sql1 = "SELECT month, AVG(price) AS 'Average Customer Price', SUM(gallons) as 'Total Customer Gallons' from customer_contracts
 group BY month";
 $cust = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
 while ($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cust))
 { 
   $cust_items[] = $rows1;
 }
```

Comment: Use `foreach` to create new array when the month name is a key.

Comment: How did you use array_unique? That should work.

Comment: @Don't Panic -- $combined = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$combined1 = array_unique($combined);
print_r($combined1);
Results:
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [month] => November [Average Purchase Price] => 2.52 [Total Purchase Gallons] => 84000 ) )

Comment: @biesior can you give me an example?
I am already using a foreach -- 
foreach($combined as $purchase){

Comment: #biesior I am getting this from 2 SQL statements, and am trying to put them together.

Comment: array_unique will work, but you need to use it just on that column rather than the entire array of arrays. Like `array_unique(array_column($combined, 'month'))`.

Comment: @Don't Panic -- That did not work.  Maybe I need to explain it better.  I am using two SQL statements to get this info, then I merge the 2 arrays. --
I then want to echo the combined array out showing the following in a <tr>,  --
Month | Purchase Price | Purchase Gallons | Customer Price | Customer Gallons --
Month2 | Purchase Price | Purchase Gallons | Customer Price | Customer Gallons

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread it. I thought you were wanting the unique months only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your original two arrays, just re-index on `month` and recursively merge them:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive(array_column($array1, null, 'month'),
                                array_column($array2, null, 'month'));
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [November] => Array
        (
            [month] => Array
                (
                    [0] => November
                    [1] => November
                )
            [Average Purchase Price] => 2.52
            [Total Purchase Gallons] => 84000
            [Average Customer Price] => 2.79
            [Total Customer Gallons] => 25000
        )
    [October] => Array
        (
            [month] => Array
                (
                    [0] => October
                    [1] => October
                )
            [Average Purchase Price] => 2.615
            [Total Purchase Gallons] => 63000
            [Average Customer Price] => 2.905
            [Total Customer Gallons] => 5500
        )
)
```

Making it easy to access any key from a month:

```
echo $result['October']['Average Purchase Price'];
echo $result['October']['Average Customer Price'];
// etc...
```

Or loop:

```
foreach($result as $month => $values) {
    echo $month;
    echo $values['Average Purchase Price'];
    echo $values['Average Customer Price'];
    // etc...
}
```

However, you edited in two queries that can be combined. This may work or ask another question and someone can undoubtedly give you one query:

```
SELECT month, AVG(price) AS 'Average Purchase Price', SUM(gallons) AS 'Total Purchase Gallons'
    FROM purchase_contracts GROUP BY month

UNION ALL

SELECT month, AVG(price) AS 'Average Customer Price', SUM(gallons) AS 'Total Customer Gallons'
    FROM customer_contracts GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked just fine.  I did post the sql but this does work.  Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: It's definitely doable in one query.  I posted an untested example.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy iteration:

```php
<?php

$oldArr = [
    ['month' => 'November', 'Average Purchase Price' => 2.52, 'Total Purchase Gallons' => 84000],
    ['month' => 'October', 'Average Purchase Price' => 2.615, 'Total Purchase Gallons' => 63000],
    ['month' => 'November', 'Average Customer Price' => 2.79, 'Total Customer Gallons' => 25000],
    ['month' => 'October', 'Average Customer Price' => 2.9050000000000002, 'Total Customer Gallons' => 5500]
];

$newArr = [];
foreach ($oldArr as $item) {
    $month = $item['month'];
    if (!array_key_exists($month, $newArr)) {
        $newArr[$month] = $item;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
```